# Instagram API search by hastag

Tags: php, instagram-api

Im trying to search images related to a specific Hashtag in Instagram, but every time I try to validate or get permissions in my API client I see an alert that say we cant do public calls to show elements in my personal page.

I try with :

```
  $url = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/snowy/media/recent?access_token=".$TOKEN;
  $ch = curl_init($url); 

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 20); 
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); 

  $json = curl_exec($ch); 
  curl_close($ch);
```

And return to me:

{"meta": {"error_type": "OAuthPermissionsException", "code": 400, "error_message": "This client has not been approved to access this resource."}}

This is related a API limitation? Preventing now using some API calls?

Comment: Is your app in sandbox mode? If not, does it have the `basic` permission scope?

Comment: yes is in sandbox mode, but the "go live" button appear disabled, and in "Details" tab are all filled.

Comment: It's disabled because you have to apply for getting permissions to access their API, and yes; there are some rate limits. However, in sandbox, you should be able to fetch your own media, given you, of course, is a sandbox user (you'll be that automatically if you created the app). Also, you cannot access User B's media with User A's access token.

Comment: If I see correctly, I need to wait to get permissions after submit a request, but only one option of the multiple ones are alowed. Now im waiting for review, (dont like this method..) thanks